# How to add sub child nodes to a child node in Treeview dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#, treeview, parent-child

Am trying to add the tree view based on the list. Am getting an out of range exception.

```
for (int i = MyList.Count; i > 0 ; i--)
{
 MyTree.Nodes.Add(MyList[i].GetP() + " " + MyList[i].GetSt());
 MyTree.Nodes[i].Nodes.Add(MyList[i].GetSe());
 MyTree.Nodes[i].Nodes[i].Nodes.Add(MyList[i].GetI());
}
```

Am able to populate the treeview with hardcoded values. i.e.,

```
MyTree.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(MyList[0].GetI());
```

Kindly help me to resolve this exception.

**Additional Details:**

I have tried for

```
MyTree.Nodes[1].Nodes[1].Nodes.Add(MyList[1].GetI());
```

It is showing the Exception.

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be a few issues with your loop

1. `int i = MyList.Count` will be 1 bigger than the max index of
   `MyList`
2. then you try access `MyTree.Nodes[i]` when only 1 item exists

try using a `++` loop instead of `--`

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyList.Count; i++)
{
     MyTree.Nodes.Add(MyList[i].GetP() + " " + MyList[i].GetSt());
     MyTree.Nodes[i].Nodes.Add(MyList[i].GetSe());
     MyTree.Nodes[i].Nodes[i].Nodes.Add(MyList[i].GetI());
}
```

Comment: I have tried the MyList.Count-1 and increment operator,  both are not working. I have added additional details in the query part.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after spending hours found a better and easy way.

Assume you have below setup.

[image: Treeview table]

and the code is below

```
protected void load_data()
    {

        string sql_text = "select * from category_master where parent_category_code = 0"; //only root categories

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sql_text;
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            string cat_code = rdr["category_code"].ToString();
            string cat_name = rdr["category_name"].ToString();

            TreeNode parent = new TreeNode();
            parent.Value = cat_code;
            parent.Text = cat_name;
            tw.Nodes.Add(parent);

            add_childs(parent, cat_code);

        }

        connection.Close();

    }


 protected void add_childs(TreeNode tn, string category_code)
    { 

        string sql_text = "select * from category_master where parent_category_code = @category_code"; 

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sql_text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category_code", category_code);
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            string  cat_code = rdr["category_code"].ToString();
            string cat_name = rdr["category_name"].ToString();

            TreeNode child = new TreeNode();
            child.Value = cat_code;
            child.Text = cat_name;
            tn.ChildNodes.Add(child);

            add_childs(child, cat_code); //calling the same function
        }

        connection.Close();

    }
```

and the output is

[image]